# Bing Ajax v7 not firing click events with IE9

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

IE9 is not firing the mouse click when displaying a polygon.  Every other browser I have tested with (including IE8) works fine.  I think the problem has something to do with the svg object not propagating the click, but I am not sure on how to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I stripped down our drawing code to help.  Using the code below you can reproduce it by clicking on the map to start drawing, clicking again below your original point, and then moving the mouse to the left and trying to click.

Note, If you double click on the map it will fire the click event.   Also, if I don't draw the tempShape on the mousemove it will work.  Also, the mouseup and mousedown events will work but this will mess with the ability to drag the map while drawing.  Here is some sample code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>
Bing Map 
</title> 
<style type="text/css">
    #divMap
    {
        height: 500px !important;
        width: 940px !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="divMap" style=""></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //<![CDATA[


    var self = {
        map: null,
        drawing: {
            points: [],
            tempPoints: [],
            stopPolygon: null,
            shapeLayer: null
        }
    };


    function init() {
        self.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), {
            credentials: "Key",
            zoom: 15,
            center: { latitude: 45.9213475137949, longitude: -90.4466233402491 }
        });


        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(self.map, 'click', drawPolyMouseClickEvent);
        self.drawing.shapeLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        self.map.entities.push(self.drawing.shapeLayer);
    }


    function drawPolyMouseClickEvent(e) {
        var x = e.getX();
        var y = e.getY();
        var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(x, y);
        var loc = self.map.tryPixelToLocation(point);
        var mouseMove = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(self.map, 'mousemove', drawPolyMouseMoveEvent);
        self.drawing.points.push(loc);
        if (self.drawing.points.length == 1) {
            self.drawing.stopPolygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, { text: " ", textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0) });
            self.drawing.shapeLayer.push(self.drawing.stopPolygon);
        }
    }


    function drawPolyMouseMoveEvent(e) {
        var x = e.getX();
        var y = e.getY();
        var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(x, y);
        var loc = self.map.tryPixelToLocation(point);
        self.drawing.tempPoints = self.drawing.points.slice(0, self.drawing.points.length);
            self.drawing.tempPoints.push(loc);
        self.drawing.shapeLayer.remove(self.drawing.tempShape);
        if (self.drawing.tempPoints.length == 2) {
            self.drawing.tempShape = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(self.drawing.tempPoints);
            self.drawing.shapeLayer.push(self.drawing.tempShape);
        }
        else if (self.drawing.tempPoints.length > 2) {
            self.drawing.tempShape = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(self.drawing.tempPoints);
            self.drawing.shapeLayer.push(self.drawing.tempShape);
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is behaving slightly strangely. It's something to do with the combination of both map events, because if you disable the move event then IE9 gets a `click` event every time.

With some playing around, I found that changing the event from `click` to `mousedown` fixed the issue. Perhaps it's because `mousedown` gets called before `mousemove` gets a chance to interfere?